# Code igniter get ajax value from view to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

How do I get **send** in my controller? This is what, I have tried out:

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "example/name",
    data: send,
    success: function(value) {

    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
class Example extends CI_Controller {
    function name() {
        $this - > post(send);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `send` variable?

Comment: @dfsq:it has an string as content. How do I send ajax values and retrieve in controller.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a function named `post` exists on your controller ? I hope that you need to fetch the `POST` values, Please use `$this->input->post('field_name')`

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you don't send your data properly. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "example/name",
    data: {send: send},
    success: function(value) {

    }
});
```

In this case you will be available as `$_POST['send']`.

Comment: How do I retrieve in my controller ?

Comment: You can get it as any other POST parameter. I'm not familiar with Codeigniter, but after quick lookup in documentation seems that you can retrieve it as `$this->input->post('send');` as well.

Comment: :In my firebug, it is showing me example/index/example/name. Why is it posting like this ? my code igniter says An Error Was Encountered
The action you have requested is not allowed.

Comment: Because the path must be `/example/name`. Front `/` makes it to be relative to the web server root.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one , this is ajax call

```
 $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>example/name',{send:send}, 
          function(data) {

      });
```

then access it using post into your controller like this

```
class Example extends CI_Controller {
function name() {
    $_POST['send'];
  }
}
```

Comment: :Now my url structure is correct but mu fire bug shows
POST http://localhost/sample/index.php/example/name
500 Internal Server Error 195ms. When I land up in this page my URL is look like this http://localhost/sample/index.php/example/data/13

Answer (score 1):

First you can define a global variable that can be used as your base url in the jquery code. Place this in the `<script>` tag of the page `<head>` section

```
         //<![CDATA[
              base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>';
        //]]>
```

Than do the ajax request like this

```
        var data  = 'var1=aaa&var2=bbb';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url+"mainController/getData/", //base_url is the variable which you have defined in the head section 
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                   alert(response);
            }
        });
```

Than in the controller retrieve the post data like this

```
       class MainController extends CI_Controller {

            function getData()
            {
               $var1 = $this->input->post('var1');
               $var2 = $this->input->post('var2');

               echo $var1;
               echo '<br/>';
               echo $var2;
            }  
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the value to be posted with the send i.e. it should be like-

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "example/name",
    data: 'send='+1,
    success: function(value) {

    }
});
```

Then you will have the value of this variable as you are doing.

using-

```
$this->input->post('send');
```

Comment: In my firebug, it is showing me example/index/example/name. Why is it posting like this ?

Comment: Try to use complete url from http to end till your functuion using <?php echo base_url();?> in script