# How to send data from view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, database, codeigniter

I am new to code-igniter. In my View I added this code to enable google login in my website.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="720765566138-5c6jreo4r7ma6cm0hdblj5cmjtdiruk4.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>     </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-onfailure="onFailure" data-theme="dark"></div>
<script>
function onFailure(msg){ console.log(msg); }
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    console.log("onSignIn");
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var user_name = profile.getName();
    var id = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I send the variable user_name and id to the Controller so that I can call the Model to insert the value to the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code igniter get ajax value from view to controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584776/code-igniter-get-ajax-value-from-view-to-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use ajax to post the information once you've gotten it (using jquery below):

```
<script>
    function onSignIn(googleUser)
   {
       var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
       var user_name = profile.getName();
       var id = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id;
       $.ajax({
               'url': 'the/path/to/controller',
               'type': 'POST',
               'data':{'user_name': user_name, 'id':id},
               'success': function(){}, //up to you
               'error': function() // up to you
             })
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make controller's action and in this you have to pass variable like this :

```
function test{
    $user_name = "XYZ";
    $this->load->view('view_name', $user_name);
    }
```

If you want to pass more than one variable then use below :

```
function test{
        $user_name = "XYZ";
        $data = 123;
        $this->load->view('view_name', array("user_name"=>$user_name,"data"=>$data));
    }
May this will help you :)
```

Comment: I wanted to send the the JavaScript variable user_name to controller from the view.

Comment: Then pass the javascript value to hidden field and pass that variable in form action url.... And you can then get that variable by $this->input->get(); in controller.

Answer (score 2):

With normal Subbmission of your `Form` or using `Ajax` if your method is `post`

```
$this->input->post();
```

this method contain all data else by default get method

```
$this->input->get();
```

Make your `form` Like below

```
 <form action="baseurl/controller_name/method">
 add hidden field of user_id then sumbmit 
 </form>
```

In Your Controller

```
  function YOUR_METHOD()
  {
      print_r($this->input->get())//By default get method
  }
```